# In Python3, how can I use the .append function to add a string to scraped links?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Thanks to stackoverflow.com I was able write a program that scrapes web links from any given web page. However, I need it to concatenate the home URL to any relative link that it comes across. (Example: "http://www.google.com/sitemap" is okay. But just "/sitemap" by itself is not okay.)

In the following code,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as mySoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin as myJoin
from urllib.request import urlopen as myRequest

base_url = "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html"

html_page = myRequest(base_url)
raw_html = html_page.read()
page_soup = mySoup(raw_html, "html.parser")
html_page.close()

f = open("census4-3.csv", "w")

all_links = page_soup.find_all('a', href=True)

def clean_links(tags, base_url):
    cleaned_links = set()
    for tag in tags:
        link = tag.get('href')
        if link is None:
            continue
        full_url = myJoin(base_url, link)
        cleaned_links.add(full_url)
    return cleaned_links

cleaned_links = clean_links(all_links, base_url)

for link in cleaned_links:
    f.write(str(link) + '\n')

f.close()
print("The CSV file is saved to your computer.")
```

how and where would I add something like this:

```
.append("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: I'm not in reach of a Python IDE to test this, hence a comment rather than an answer. For starters the `.append` method works on lists, not strings. To combine strings in Python use a +. You can also use += the same way you would increment a numerical variable. For instance redefining the string `a="Hello"` as `a="Hello world"`; `a+=" world"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save your base url as `base_url = 'https://www.census.gov'`.

Call the requests like this

```
html_page = myRequest(base_url + '/programs-surveys/popest.html')
```

When you want to get any `full_url`, just do this

```
full_url = base_url + link
```

Comment: You will need to be sure that both variables are strings though.

Comment: No need for that in OP's code. `link = tag.get('href')` will either be a **string** or `None`, and he's handled the case for `None`.